# Bump map sprite casting shadows on itself

Tags: three.js, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

I've got a fairly simple implementation of normal map lighting working for 2D sprites in webgl (GLSL shaders) which I was able to adapt & optimize from an example. It uses just one directional light and works fine for my purposes. Sprites are rendered flat (2D), only the light direction and normals are 3D vectors. Vertex rotation only happens around the z axis, so it's fairly easy-peasy.

I was hoping to add a bump (height) map to cast shadows. There are 3D bump map shadow casting examples and papers available online, but they're more complex than I need and the math goes over my head; I haven't found an example or explanation of how one might do a simple 2D case.

My first inclination is as follows: for the current pixel in the fragment shader, trace back along the direction of the light and check the altitude of the neighbouring bump map pixel. If it's higher than the light direction vector at that point, then that pixel is in the shade. However since "tall" pixels on the bump map may cast shadow across > 1 pixel distance, I'd have to keep testing pixel by pixel in that direction until I find one tall enough to cast a shadow (or reach the edge of the texture, or reach some arbitrary limit.)

This doesn't sound very optimal, especially for larger textures. I've read that if statements in shaders aren't so fast. Is there a faster/better method?

Comment: Google parallax mapping. It seems like you looking for that. Tell me if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the terms, that improved my Google searches a lot. I've browsed a few PDFs. Reading [this one](http://graphics.cs.brown.edu/games/SteepParallax/mcguire-steepparallax.pdf) if I'm not mistaken, they essentially do what I wrote above - trace from the current pixel back along the light direction until it strikes a height value that would shadow it (or not.) Found a [webgl example here](http://lib3d.fr/webgl/?obj=plane&nor=brickNorm.png&tex=brick.png&srx=0.02) too. Not sure if there are some optimizations I'm missing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called parallax (occlusion) mapping.

It's a technique that does exactly what you described, and it can be understood as on-bumpmap ray tracing in tangent space.

Here are some articles:

- [nVidia - Per-Pixel displacement (w/ sphere tracing)](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter08.html)
- [nVidia - Cone Tracing for PM](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch18.html)
- [AMD - POM](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Tatarchuk-POM.pdf)

The ways to optimize search are similar to ordinary raytracing and include: sphere tracing, cone tracing, binary search and similar, instead of constant stepping function.

P. S. If you know the name of some rendering technique, it's generally good idea to Google it adding 'nVidia', 'crytek' or 'gpu' in front of the name, it will show you much more relevant results.

Hope this helps.